How to unlock windows user session
I have written a python program which perform web data scrapping automation on browser. To execute these scripts, my requirement is to unlock the Windows session to allow interaction with UI elements in the browser, essentially for browser-based automation.
I am seeking your expertise to determine if there is a way to unlock the Windows instance session?
Thank you!
I tried WfreeRDp.exe but it does not meet my requirement. My expectation is to unlock the windows session before my python script get executed on machine
